# Plotly цикличная анимация

Tags: python, plotly

Коллеги, нужна помощь, по задаче сделал столбчатый график на plotly,особо дашбордами не занимался, но в доке разобравшись собрал. Проблема такая: по бренду проходится анимация и идет ползунок и показывает выработку сотрудников относительно бренду, то есть по оси x у меня ползунок катается по 15 указанным брендам. Не получается сделать цикличную анимацию. Дашборд выводится на экран телевизора, то есть нужно все действия свести к нулю. У меня django приложения до всех дашбордов сделал маршрутизацию, как только редиректит на любой дашборд у него срабатывает автоматом стоковая видимо анимация и на огромной скорости проходится по всем брендам. Потом останавливается я нашел код в инете по кнопке Play. Когда я её жму переодически анимация циклична, но из-за этого по оси Y план сотрудников статичен, то есть самая верхняя грань оси Y становится 35k когда план сотрудников по некоторым брендам по миллионам и из-за этого графики не адаптируются и бьются в потолок, это происходит только тогда, когда я запускаю анимацию по кнопке play.Может кто сталкивался с этим, подскажите

```
fig = px.bar(df, 
             x="Менеджер", 
             y=["Сумма текущий", "Сумма план"],
             barmode='group', 
             width=1900,
             animation_frame="Бренд")

# Настройка параметров анимации
    fig.update_layout(
        updatemenus=[{
            "buttons": [
                {"args": [None, {"frame": {"duration": 2000, "redraw": True}, "fromcurrent": True}],
                "label": "Play",
                "method": "animate"}
            ],
            "type": "buttons",
            "showactive": False,
        }],
        sliders=[{
            "active": len(df['Бренд'].unique()) - 1,
            "yanchor": "top",
            "xanchor": "left",
            "currentvalue": {
                "font": {"size": 16},
                "prefix": "Бренд: ",
                "visible": True,
                "xanchor": "right"
            },
            "transition": {"duration": 2000, "easing": "cubic-in-out"},
            "pad": {"b": 10},
            "len": 1.0,
        }]
    )
```